# Пример приложения WPF+MVVM+EF6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Здравствуйте.
Не могли бы вы мне показать небольшой пример кода приложения, сделанного на WPF (C#) согласно паттерну MVVM и следующим условиям:

1. В модели некоторая сущность, которая грузится из БД средствами Entity Framework. Модель ничего не знает про View и ViewModel.
2. В модели представления эта сущность как раз подгружается в коллекцию, допустим, ElementList. Также есть свойство SelectedElement, которое будет представлять текущую (выбранную из таблицы) запись, и команды для операций с данными (CRUD). ViewModel знает про Model, но ничего не знает про View.
3. В представлении есть 2 окна: главное содержит таблицу со списком элементов и кнопки (добавить, редактировать, удалить). И есть окно-редактор, в котором редактируется текущий элемент. Оба окна в качестве контекста данных используют одну и ту же модель представления (редактор оперирует только со свойством SelectedElement). Все кнопки в представлении привязаны к командам. View ничего не знает про Model, лишь только привязана контекстом данных к ViewModel.

   Собственно, с чем у меня возникли сложности и вопросы:

   1. Как в рамках паттерна MVVM взаимодействовать между главным окном и редактором (примеров в интернете полно, но все простейшие и для полноценного приложения далеко не всегда подходят, так что толку от них мало)?
   2. Каким образом строить модель представления, чтобы таблица в главном окне обновлялась автоматически в соответствии с изменениями в БД?

Буду благодарен, если предоставите прям код, который делает это все адекватно и без танцев с бубном. Нужно учесть, что пишу большое приложение, где таких сущностей будет уйма (порядка, 140), хотелось бы поэкономить время, силы и нервы.

Comment: Подхватывание изменений из базы данных — больная тема, т. к. это не описывается CRUD-операциями. Смотрите в сторону `SqlDependency` для SQL Server, например.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Но что делать с окнами? Это основной вопрос.

Comment: А что с ними делать такого необычного? Ну, у вас обычное MVVM-приложение с базой в модели, оно по сути ничем ни отличается от любой другой модели.

Answer (score 3):

Совсем небольшого нет. Есть на 3 десятка окон. Суть: список сущностей в DataGrid  +  кнопки/меню  добавить/редактировать/удалить/показать сущность.  Каждое действие (кроме удалить) в новом окне. При сохранении изменений  данные в БД и DataGrid  обновляются. Подойдет?
Если надо, я вытяну куски кода, но проще дать ссылку на bitbucket.org. Там лежит полная версия.

Comment: Да, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/hind19/portflio/src/6ec429c9706a36ace379cdb3b215a6fe9d31f37a/Contracts_v2/?at=default     Решение Contracs_v2. ДатаГридов там несколько, самый упитанный в главном окне (ViewModel/ViewModelMainWindow - вьюмодель, окно - MainWindow в корне). За вызов новых окон по командам отвечает класс View/ViewRequest.cs

Comment: Если какие вопросы по проекту, спрашивайте

Answer (score 2):

[Пример](https://github.com/Teren2304/BlockApp) построения графика на OxyPlot, работа с БД, обновляемыми данными парсингом, и списками